# Cannot validate view.model.product.ProductSearchCriteria. No bean introspection present. Please add @Introspected to the class

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Custom validator issue **No bean introspection present. Please add @Introspected to the class and ensure Micronaut annotation processing is enabled** not working Micronaut 2.2.1

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface LastProductIdRequired {
    String message() default "Product id is required for pagination if current page is greater then 0";
}
```

**Factory**

```
@Factory
public class LastProductIdRequiredFactory {
    @Singleton
    ConstraintValidator<LastProductIdRequired, PaginationViewModel> lastProductIdRequired() {
        return (value, annotationMetadata, context) ->
                value != null && (value.getCurrentPage() > 0 && value.getLastProductId() != null);
    }
}
```

**POJO**

```
@Introspected
public class PaginationViewModel {
    int pageSize = 10;
    int total = 0;
    int currentPage = 0;
    int totalPage = 0;
    @LastProductIdRequired
    String lastProductId;
    ....
}


@Introspected
public class ProductSearchCriteria extends PaginationViewModel{

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller("/product")
@Validated
public class ProductController {
@Get(value = "/{?searchCriteria*}")
public Maybe<FindProductViewModel> find(@Valid ProductSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
        return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
{
    "message": "searchCriteria: Cannot validate view.model.product.ProductSearchCriteria. No bean introspection present. Please add @Introspected to the class and ensure Micronaut annotation processing is enabled",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/v1/product",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65262214/validating-the-pojo-record-with-micronaut-not-working/65530466#65530466

Comment: Do you have  the `io.micronaut:micronaut-validation` annotation processor dependency configured in your build?

Answer (score 0):

You can run such kind of method, and provide **ProductSearchCriteria** as argument

> `private Set<String> getIntrospectedProperties(Class<?> productSearchCriteria) {` 
> `final BeanIntrospection<?> introspection =` 
>  `BeanIntrospection.getIntrospection(productSearchCriteria);` 
> `return Arrays.stream(introspection.getPropertyNames()).collect(Collectors.toSet());` 
> `}`