# Validate model from other module with micronaut gives "No bean introspection present."

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, gradle-kotlin-dsl, micronaut-data, micronaut-rest

When I try to send object in body of POST method to micronaut application I get:
*model: Cannot validate com.example.Model. No bean introspection present. Please add @Introspected to the class and ensure Micronaut annotation processing is enabled*.

The structure of the project consist of two modules *main* and *model*. The *main* module have dependency to the *model* module.

The *main* module contains only of the *DefaultTestController* class:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.validation.Validated
import javax.validation.Valid

@Controller("/test")
@Validated
class DefaultTestController : TestController {

    @Post
    override fun create(@Body @Valid model: Model) {
        println("Model: $model")
    }
}
```

And its *build.gradle.kts* file looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.6.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.6.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.6.0"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.0.2"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

val kotlinVersion = project.properties.get("kotlinVersion")
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation:3.2.2")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client:3.2.2")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:3.2.2")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime:3.0.0")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.0.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.7")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:3.2.2")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.0")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:3.2.2")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:3.2.2")

    implementation(project(":model"))
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

The *model* module contains:

1. *Model* class:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected
import javax.validation.Valid

@Introspected
data class Model(
    @field:Valid
    val subModel: SubModel
)
```

2. *SubModel* class:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected
import javax.validation.constraints.Email

@Introspected
data class SubModel(
    @field:Email
    val email: String
)
```

And its *build.gradle.kts* file looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:3.2.2")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:3.2.2")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation:3.2.2")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation:3.2.2")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:3.2.2")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:3.2.2")
}
```

The *gradle.properties* file:

```
micronautVersion=3.2.2
kotlinVersion=1.6.0
org.gradle.java.installations.auto-download=false
org.gradle.java.installations.auto-detect=false
org.gradle.java.installations.fromEnv=JAVA_HOME
```

When I move the *Model* and *SubModel* to the *main* module everything works as expected.
When I remove `@Validated` and `@Valid` annotations from *DefaultTestController* then it is also working, but the email is not validated.

I tried many different possibilities of adding and removing various dependencies (e.g. described here: [Validating the POJO record with Micronaut not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65262214/validating-the-pojo-record-with-micronaut-not-working/65530466) and [Cannot validate view.model.product.ProductSearchCriteria. No bean introspection present. Please add @Introspected to the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273370/cannot-validate-view-model-product-productsearchcriteria-no-bean-introspection)) but nothing worked as expected. Can someone take a look and help me solve this problem?

EDIT:
Here is the repository with code example: [github.com/stefanik36/Micronaut-Introspection-Problem](https://github.com/stefanik36/Micronaut-Introspection-Problem). It contains `src/test/kotlin/com/example/DefaultTestControllerTest.kt` test which will pass when the `Model` and `SubModel` classes will be moved to the main module.

Comment: Hi. If you have/create a GitHub repo with your code that we can fork, chances for getting this resolved quick will improve. BR

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. Here is the repo: https://github.com/stefanik36/Micronaut-Introspection-Problem. It contains `src/test/kotlin/com/example/DefaultTestControllerTest.kt` test which will pass when the `Model` and `SubModel` class will be moved to the main module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by including of **io.micronaut.library** gradle plugin in **model** gradle module and then only `io.micronaut:micronaut-validation` implementation dependency is required.

After these changes content of the *model/build.gradle.kts* file will look like:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
    id("io.micronaut.library")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
}
```

After this change validation defined in classes from separate gradle module and annotated by `@Introspected` will work.

Comment: That solves my problem. Thank you.

Comment: `implementation("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation")`